# Remove unselectable="on" with JS ( chrome extension )

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to copy text from a `div` or remove the `unselectable="on"` from the whole HTML document with chrome extension, here is the HTML code for that.

```html
<div unselectable="on" class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-agentAuthId"> 3607619964 / 5768287729 </div>
```

I made an extension where I can manipulate with `id`, but I have no `id` in my HTML. I only have `class`, and there are too many classes, so I can't get the part I neeed (3607619964 / 5768287729).

I intend to remove the `unselectable="on"` attribute , but I don't know how ...

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think is:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[unselectable="on"]').forEach(el => el.removeAttribute('unselectable'));
```

It selects all elements with the `unselectable` attribute set to `on` using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), loops through the returned [`nodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) with `forEach` and then removes the attribute with [`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute).

Comment: Thanks the element is removed but i cant still select the text :/ is there any way  after remove to copy the text like 3607619964 / 5768287729 and console.log or alert it ?

Comment: @GiorgiShonia change the `forEach()` to contain `el=> el.removeAttribute('unselectable'); console.log(el.textContent);`

Comment: Thanks mate u saved my life <3